# table header and body with object

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kinda new to javascript and tables and i want to create the table header based on headings object and match the table body with the items object. in this example i've tried with an array.

```
var data = [
    ['Book', 'Author', 'Year'],
    ['The Great Gatsby', 'Scott Fitzgerald', '1925'],
    ['The Grapes of Wrath', 'John Steinbeck', '1939'],
    ['A Wild Sheep Chase', 'Haruki Murakami', '1982']
  ] 
  
  var table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table);

data.forEach(function(row) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr'); /
  table.appendChild(tr); 
  row.forEach(function(column) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td.innerText = column; 
  });
});
```

but instead of the data array i want to build the same table with data object instead. what can i change at my function?

```
"data": {
    "headings": [
      {
        "displayName": "Book",
        "columnID": "bookID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Author",
        "columnID": "authorID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Year",
        "columnID": "yearID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "",
        "columnID": "urlID"
      }
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "bookID": "The Great Gatsby",
        "authorID": " F Scott Fitzgerald",
        "yearID": "1925",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      },
      {
        "bookID": "The Grapes of Wrath",
        "authorID": "John Steinbeck",
        "yearID": "1939",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Wild Sheep Chase",
        "authorID": "Haruki Murakami",
        "yearID": "1982",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Farewell to Arms",
        "authorID": "Ernest Hemingway",
        "yearID": "1929",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the object for `for in`.

```js
var data =  {
    "headings": [
      {
        "displayName": "Book",
        "columnID": "bookID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Author",
        "columnID": "authorID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Year",
        "columnID": "yearID"
      },
      {
        "displayName": "",
        "columnID": "urlID"
      }
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "bookID": "The Great Gatsby",
        "authorID": " F Scott Fitzgerald",
        "yearID": "1925",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      },
      {
        "bookID": "The Grapes of Wrath",
        "authorID": "John Steinbeck",
        "yearID": "1939",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Wild Sheep Chase",
        "authorID": "Haruki Murakami",
        "yearID": "1982",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      },
      {
        "bookID": "A Farewell to Arms",
        "authorID": "Ernest Hemingway",
        "yearID": "1929",
        "urlID": "https://google.com"
      }
    ]
  }
  
  
var table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table);

for (const field in data) {
   if(field == "headings"){
      var tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
      for (const child in data.headings) {
         var td = document.createElement('td');
         tr.appendChild(td);
         td.innerText = data.headings[child].displayName; 
         table.appendChild(tr);
       }
   }
   else if(field == "items"){
      for (const child in data.items) {
         var tr = document.createElement('tr'); 
         let item = data.items[child];
         for (const row in item) {
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          tr.appendChild(td);
          td.innerText = item[row]; 
          table.appendChild(tr);
         }
       }
   }
}
```

```css
table{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `.forEach()` function on an object.

You can create two functions, where one of them is responsible for creating head part of the table and second function is responsible for creating body part of the table. Pass the `headings` array to the function that is responsible for creating table's head and pass `items` array to the function that is responsible for creating table's body.

```js
const data = {
  headings: [
    { displayName: 'Book', columnID: 'bookID' },
    { displayName: 'Author', columnID: 'authorID' },
    { displayName: 'Year', columnID: 'yearID' },
    { displayName: 'URL', columnID: 'urlID' }
  ],
  items: [
    { bookID: 'The Great Gatsby', authorID: ' F Scott Fitzgerald', yearID: '1925', urlID: 'https://google.com' },
    { bookID: 'The Grapes of Wrath', authorID: 'John Steinbeck', yearID: '1939', urlID: 'https://google.com', },
    { bookID: 'A Wild Sheep Chase', authorID: 'Haruki Murakami', yearID: '1982', urlID: 'https://google.com', },
    { bookID: 'A Farewell to Arms', authorID: 'Ernest Hemingway', yearID: '1929', urlID: 'https://google.com' }
  ]
};

function displayTable(data) {
  const table = document.createElement('table');

  createTableHead(table, data.headings);
  createTableBody(table, data.items);

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

function createTableHead(table, headings) {
  const tHead = table.createTHead();
  const headRow = tHead.insertRow();

  headings.forEach(({displayName}) => {
    const th = document.createElement('th');
    th.textContent = displayName;
    headRow.appendChild(th);
  });
}

function createTableBody(table, items) {
  const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

  items.forEach(({bookID, authorID, yearID, urlID}) => {
    const row = tbody.insertRow();
    row.insertCell().textContent = bookID;
    row.insertCell().textContent = authorID;
    row.insertCell().textContent = yearID;
    row.insertCell().textContent = urlID;
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
}

displayTable(data);
```

```css
table, tr, th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```